# I can't get an ADC value, and in ADC conversion mode I can only get data once (MCP3561/2/4)

Tags: stm32, adc, spi

I'm using an STM32H7 microcontroller. I can write to the registers, but they are not correct. I set the IRQ register to 0x06, but I read 0x76. I connected AVDD and DVDD to 3.3 V, but IRQ is connected to 1.8 V (design fault). SPI config:

```
hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 0x7;
hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;
hspi1.Init.NSSPolarity = SPI_NSS_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi1.Init.FifoThreshold = SPI_FIFO_THRESHOLD_01DATA;
hspi1.Init.TxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
hspi1.Init.RxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
hspi1.Init.MasterSSIdleness = SPI_MASTER_SS_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
hspi1.Init.MasterInterDataIdleness = SPI_MASTER_INTERDATA_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
hspi1.Init.MasterReceiverAutoSusp = SPI_MASTER_RX_AUTOSUSP_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.MasterKeepIOState = SPI_MASTER_KEEP_IO_STATE_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.IOSwap = SPI_IO_SWAP_DISABLE;
if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does it surprise you to read 0x76 from the MCP356x's IRQ register? The upper bits in that register are status bits, while the lower bits are exactly what you set them to.

Comment: Sorry, i miss that but now i understand why i always read same data. But how can i make it right. 0x7 means ADCDATA has not been updated since last reading. Why its not updating.

Comment: Are you sure you're supplying a valid clock signal to the ADC's MCLK pin? Try configuring the ADC to use its internal clock by setting bit 5 in the Config0 register (change your spi1Tx[1] from 0x03 to 0x43).

Answer (score 1):

spi1Tx[1]= 0x03;

in this line you have used bits[5:4] = 00 = External digital clock.
I hope you are providing external clock. if not please change the setting to
bits[5:4] = 10 this will make sure the ADC is working and you can see IRQ updating and data updating.